# Python 2.7 and 3.5 Windows Install

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda

I have both 2.7 and the latest 3.5 Anaconda Python version installed.

2.7 is my old one and I just installed the 3.5 one today. The first time when I installed 3.5 today I downloaded the .exe from their website. I used Pycharm IDE so when I went in there to change the interpreter i got the following error message:

```
Cannot set up a python SDK at c:\user\asd\Anaconda\...\python.exe
This SDK is invalid.
```

I tried to add it to my path but that didn't solve my problem.

The second approach i tried is to uninstall it and install it via conda as a second environment.

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
activate py35
```

All this worked and when I successfully activated it I typed python and this error came up:

```
Fatal Python Error: Py_Initializer: unable to load the file system codec
File "C:\User\asd\Anaconda\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\

SyntaxError: Invalid syntax

Current Thread 0x00001bb8 <most recent call first>:
```

I am totally confused on what the problem is and why i cant seem to run python3.5 with python 2.7 also installed.

thanks

[image]

Comment: That `raise` syntax in the error message indicates your 3.5 Python is loading source files that are strictly Py2 (the comma separated `raise Class, [Message, [Traceback]]` syntax doesn't exist in Py3). Something tells me you installed a Py2 package you shouldn't have (`encodinga` is not a package in the default install to my knowledge, unless it's some Anaconda specific thing), and did so in the wrong way (it's not installed in a version dependent `site-packages` directory).

Comment: sorry its `encodings`, mis spelled....i just uploaded the exact error

Comment: Did you manually modify anything in your environment variables, e.g. `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: I added the `C:\Users\Wei\Anaconda\envs\py35` to my path in environment variables. is PythonPath different from this?

Comment: Yes, it's separate. `echo %PYTHONPATH%` would tell you if it were set to anything.

Comment: I didn't touch that...but here is what I have `C:\Users\Wei\Anaconda\Lib;C:\Users\Wei\Anaconda\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Users\Wei\Dropbox\Work\Personal\Python`

Comment: Well, that first entry is your broken entry; I don't know Anaconda, but you clearly have Py2-only stuff installed there, so it shouldn't be in your `PYTHONPATH` (which is used by both Py2 and Py3). Someone else may know more about how Anaconda is supposed to be configured.